# How to use conditional operations in python?

Tags: python

```
x+=5 if x+5<10 else 0
```

In this above example i should add 5 to x if x+5 is less than 10.

but as you can see i am calculating x+5 two times how can i do without repeating it.

like
`"add x to 5 if it doesnt become greater than 10 after adding"`

is this possible on python? if yes then how do you do that?

Comment: "but as you can see i am calculating x+5 two times how can i do without repeating it." *Why is it a problem* to repeat the calculation? Do you just want some "more elegant" way to get the correct new value for `x`? Does it have to use a conditional expression? What actually is the *question* here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Python 3.8, there is the new "walrus" operator. `:=`, which allows assignments as expressions, just like the `=` operator behaves in C like languages.

You can rewrite your expression as:

```
x = y if (y:= x + 5) < 10 else x
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you could convert this expression:

```
x + 5 < 10
```

into this:

```
x < 5
```

Then rephrase your if else one liner as:

```py
x += 5 if x < 5 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# We know x+=5 is same as x = x + 5
# for the conditional x + 5 < 10 is rewritten as x < 5
# We define a range for x. 
for x in range (10):
    x = x + 5
    print(x)
if x<5 :
    print(x)

else:
    x=0
```